# Getting wrong number when using count - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to get the total number of questions based on specific categories. So i used the below line of code but it returns wrong number and i cannot understand why i cannot access questions directly from a "where" query.

```
def questions_total
    number = Category.where("tag LIKE ?",'1-%').includes(:questions).count
  end
```

please guide me through my mistakes thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `GROUP BY` SQL syntax:

```
Question.group(:category_id)
        .joins(:category).where('categories.tag LIKE ?', '1-%')
        .count
```

You can delete the `joins` line if you don't want to apply any filter based on the Category attribute.

Comment: erm in my view i get this i guess hashes , `{2=>3, 10=>1} of {2=>3, 10=>1} questions remaining` it should say `4 of 4 questions remaining`

Comment: Yes, this is correct. The key of the Hash is the category id, the value is the number of questions in that category. As you can see, you can get the full count in a single query. Now it's up to you to reuse such information according to what you want to do in your code.

Comment: i think i didnt clarify enough. what i need is the total number by summing up all the questions in the categories that are based on a certain tag range. so how do i get the number 4 after that?

Comment: As I explained, this query returns such information grouped per category. You have two option now: (1) adapt the query even further using a little bit of SQL effort to have the DBMS to return a single value or (2) sum the values of the Hash with a very simple 1-line Ruby expression and return the final count.

Comment: i have no clue how to do either. should i add `sum` at the end? or loop through or something else?

Answer (score 0):

`Category.where("tag LIKE ?",'1-%').questions.distinct.count`

I'm assuming that there is an association, and provably you are getting the wrong number because a question can have more than one category(many to many) so you are getting repetitions, distinct will leave just one case of each